# woocommerce woocommerce_payment_complete hook is not working?

Tags: woocommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'payment_complete_func' );

function payment_complete_func(){

    file_get_contents("http://localhost/wordpress/test.php?id=paymentagain2");
}
```

I am using paypal sandbox mode for payment checking, and this function payment_complete_func() is never fired. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

The question is pretty old but it still comes up in google, so I'll leave an answer here.

PayPal payments are considered complete only when your website receives a confirmation of the payment from PayPal (called IPN - Instant Payment Notification). To do that, PayPal has to reach you, which means that your development website has to be somehow reachable from the outside through the URL that is given to PayPal.

In your case you have localhost as the url, which will never work to reach you. To correct the problem you need to either have a registered domain name for the dev environment or use the public IP address. If you are working on an offline development installation, you will have to make it available online so that PayPal can reach it.